# how to use radgrid AllowAutomaticInserts, and insertcommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I'm new to Asp.net and Telerik Control. 
I'm using Radgrid to bind a View with schemabinding in SQL Server. And I want to use Telerik Radgrid AllowAutomaticInserts/updates/deletes functions. but there is no result return to database and no error occured. When should I use Insertcommand in code-behind? How to debug aspx file as following at runtime.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code.

```
   <asp:Panel ID="Project"  runat="server"  GroupingText="Project" CssClass="inlineBlock" Width="1600px" Font-Names="Microsoft YaHei UI"
     BackColor ="#99ff99" BorderStyle="Double">
    <asp:Label Text="CompanyName" runat="server" Font-Size="Small"></asp:Label>
    <telerik:RadDropDownList ID="RadDropDownListCompany" runat="server"  Skin="Windows7" Font-Size="Small" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadDropDownListCompany_SelectedIndexChanged" 
          ></telerik:RadDropDownList>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Label Text="Projectname" runat="server" Font-Size="Small"></asp:Label>
     <telerik:RadDropDownList ID="RadDropDownListProject" runat="server"  Skin="Windows7" Font-Size="Small" ></telerik:RadDropDownList>
     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <telerik:RadButton ID="btnQuery" runat="server" Text="Confirm" Skin="Windows7" Font-Size="Small" OnClick="btnQuery_Click" ></telerik:RadButton>
</asp:Panel>

  <asp:Panel ID="PanelOp" runat="server" Visible="false" >
  <asp:Label Text="LandBlock" runat="server" Font-Size="Medium" Font-Names="Microsoft YaHei UI"></asp:Label>
<telerik:RadDropDownList ID="RadDropDownListLandBlock" runat="server"  Skin="Windows7" Font-Size="Small" Font-Names="Microsoft YaHei UI"></telerik:RadDropDownList>
<telerik:RadButton ID="radbtnLandBlockQuery" runat="server" Text="Confirm" Skin="Windows7" Font-Size="Small"  OnClick="radbtnLandBlockQuery_Click" ></telerik:RadButton>
   <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGridLandBlockVoucher" runat="server" Skin="Windows7" Font-Size="Small"  Font-Names="Microsoft YaHei UI" Culture="zh-CN" 
     Height="600px" Width="1600px" GroupPanelPosition="Top" ShowFooter ="True"  EnableViewState="true"  AutoGenerateEditColumn="true"  AutoGenerateDeleteColumn="true"
            AllowAutomaticInserts="true" AllowAutomaticUpdates="true" AllowAutomaticDeletes="true"  OnNeedDataSource="RadGridLandBlockVoucher_NeedDataSource"  >
        <ClientSettings>
            <Scrolling AllowScroll="True" UseStaticHeaders="True" />
        </ClientSettings>
        <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="PK_Landdetail" CommandItemDisplay="Top"
                CommandItemSettings-AddNewRecordText="Add"   >
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PK_Landdetail" DataType="System.Guid" FilterControlAltText="Filter PK_Landdetail column" HeaderText="PK_Landdetail" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="PK_Landdetail" UniqueName="PK_Landdetail" Visible="false" >
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PK_location" DataType="System.Int32" FilterControlAltText="Filter PK_location column" HeaderText="PK_location" SortExpression="PK_location" UniqueName="PK_location" Visible="false" ReadOnly="true"  >
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ProjectName" FilterControlAltText="Filter ProjectName column" HeaderText="ProjectName" SortExpression="ProjectName" UniqueName="ProjectName" ReadOnly="true"  >
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PK_land" DataType="System.Guid" FilterControlAltText="Filter PK_land column" HeaderText="PK_land" SortExpression="PK_land" UniqueName="PK_land" Visible="false" ReadOnly="true" >
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="LandBlockNumber" FilterControlAltText="Filter LandBlockNumber column" HeaderText="LandBlockNumber" SortExpression="LandBlockNumber" UniqueName="LandBlockNumber" ReadOnly="true" >
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PK_ccode" DataType="System.Int32" FilterControlAltText="Filter PK_ccode column" HeaderText="PK_ccode" SortExpression="PK_ccode" UniqueName="PK_ccode" Visible="false" ReadOnly="true"  >
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter ccodenamefull column" HeaderText="科目" SortExpression="ccodenamefull" UniqueName="ccodenamefull">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                         <%# Eval("ccodenamefull") %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                  <EditItemTemplate>
                        <telerik:RadDropDownList runat="server" ID="RadDropDownListCcode" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceccode" DataValueField="PK_ccode" DataTextField="ccodenamefull" SelectedValue='<%# Eval ("ccodenamefull") %>' Width="200px" ></telerik:RadDropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PayableAmount" DataType="System.Decimal" FilterControlAltText="Filter PayableAmount column" HeaderText="PayableAmount" SortExpression="PayableAmount" UniqueName="PayableAmount">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ActualAmount" DataType="System.Decimal" FilterControlAltText="Filter ActualAmount column" HeaderText="ActualAmount" SortExpression="ActualAmount" UniqueName="ActualAmount">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ContractNo" FilterControlAltText="Filter ContractNo column" HeaderText="ContractNo" SortExpression="ContractNo" UniqueName="ContractNo">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ContractName" FilterControlAltText="Filter ContractName column" HeaderText="ContractName" SortExpression="ContractName" UniqueName="ContractName">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="LandTransferArea" DataType="System.Decimal" FilterControlAltText="Filter LandTransferArea column" HeaderText="LandTransferArea" SortExpression="LandTransferArea" UniqueName="LandTransferArea">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="LandLisenceArea" DataType="System.Decimal" FilterControlAltText="Filter LandLisenceArea column" HeaderText="LandLisenceArea" SortExpression="LandLisenceArea" UniqueName="LandLisenceArea">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="LisenceNo" FilterControlAltText="Filter LisenceNo column" HeaderText="LisenceNo" SortExpression="LisenceNo" UniqueName="LisenceNo">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="InvoiceAmount" DataType="System.Decimal" FilterControlAltText="Filter InvoiceAmount column" HeaderText="InvoiceAmount" SortExpression="InvoiceAmount" UniqueName="InvoiceAmount">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="LisenceStartDate" DataType="System.DateTime" FilterControlAltText="Filter LisenceStartDate column" HeaderText="证照起始日" SortExpression="LisenceStartDate" UniqueName="LisenceStartDate"> 
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("LisenceStartDate") %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                       <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="RadDatePickerLisenceStartDate" runat="server"  DbSelectedDate=  '<%# Bind("LisenceStartDate") %>' MinDate="1900-1-1" ></telerik:RadDatePicker>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="LisenceEndDate" DataType="System.DateTime" FilterControlAltText="Filter LisenceEndDate column" HeaderText="LisenceEndDate" SortExpression="LisenceEndDate" UniqueName="LisenceEndDate">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Note" FilterControlAltText="Filter Note column" HeaderText="Note" SortExpression="Note" UniqueName="Note">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            </Columns>
        </MasterTableView>

    </telerik:RadGrid>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceLandblockCostView" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myAsystemstring %>"
         SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [LD_LandblockCostView] WHERE [PK_location] = @PK_location AND [PK_land] = @PK_land"
         DeleteCommand="delete * from  [LD_LandblockCostView] WHERE PK_Landdetail=@PK_Landdetail" 
         InsertCommand ="INSERT INTO [LD_LandblockCostView] ([PK_location], [PK_land], [PK_ccode], [PayableAmount],  [ActualAmount], [ContractNo], [ContractName], [LandTransferArea], [LandLisenceArea], [LisenceNo], [invoiceAmount], [Note], [LisenceStartDate], [LisenceEndDate])
                                      VALUES (@PK_location,@PK_land,    @PK_ccode,@PayableAmount,   @ActualAmount,  @ContractNo,@ContractName,@LandTransferArea,@LandLisenceArea,@LisenceNo,@invoiceAmount,@Note,@LisenceStartDate,@LisenceEndDate)" 
         UpdateCommand="UPDATE [LD_LandblockCostView] SET [PK_ccode] = @PK_ccode, [PayableAmount] = @PayableAmount, [ActualAmount]=@ActualAmount,[ContractNo]=@ContractNo,[ContractName]=@ContractName,[LandTransferArea]=@LandTransferArea,[LandLisenceArea]=@LandLisenceArea,[LisenceNo]=@LisenceNo,[invoiceAmount]=@invoiceAmount,[Note]=@Note,[LisenceStartDate]=@LisenceStartDate,[LisenceEndDate]=@LisenceEndDate
                                     WHERE [PK_Landdetail] = @PK_Landdetail" >

        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="RadDropDownListProject" Name="PK_location" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="RadDropDownListLandBlock" Name="PK_land" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name ="PK_Landdetail"  Type="String" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="PK_location" Type="Int32" ControlID="RadDropDownListCompany" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="PK_land" Type="String" ControlID="RadDropDownListLandBlock" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="PK_ccode" Type="Int32" ControlID="RadDropDownListCcode" PropertyName ="SelectedValue" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="PayableAmount" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ActualAmount" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ContractNo" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ContractName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="LandTransferArea" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="LandLisenceArea" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="LisenceNo" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="invoiceAmount" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Note" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="LisenceStartDate" Type ="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="LisenceEndDate" Type="DateTime" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name ="PK_ccode" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="PayableAmount" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ActualAmount" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ContractNo" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ContractName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="LandTransferArea" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="LandLisenceArea" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="LisenceNo" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="invoiceAmount" Type="Decimal" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Note" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="LisenceStartDate" Type ="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="LisenceEndDate" Type="DateTime" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceccode" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myAsystemstring %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [PK_ccode], [ccodenamefull] FROM [Ref_ccodenameLandBlockCost]" ></asp:SqlDataSource>

    </asp:Panel>
```

Code-behind

```
  protected void RadGridLandBlockVoucher_NeedDataSource(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {
        RadGridLandBlockVoucher.DataSource = SqlDataSourceLandblockCostView;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the SQL queries defined in a declarative data source. Use that for the DataSourceID of the grid and remove the NeedDataSource handler. The SELECT query will handler your data retrieval.

If you want to use the NeedDataSource event to use some custom data access layer/logic, you should then disable the automatic operations and use the events to write your own code according to your logic/DAL.